# How can I make a smaller UIView from presentModalViewController function?

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview

I would like to ask if I would like to create a custom UIView which is just like a bubble popup, can I use presentModalViewController?

How can I custom the size?

If not, then I need to use addsubView? But the controller is still the previous one, how can I close it from the new created uiview?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I can solve it by myself.

I add a new UIViewController, and custom it by BI. 
and set below few lines,

```
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, controller.view.frame.size.width,controller.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
[self addChildViewController:controller];
```

If you want to delete them by below,

```
UIView* subview = [self.view viewWithTag:STORE_VIEW_TAG];
[subview removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```